# url rewriting doesnt work for pages in subdomain

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to change `abc.mydomain.com/xyz.php?id3=se`
 to `abc.mydomain.com/xyz/se/` with url rewriting.
 Here is my code in .htaccess (placed in abc folder)

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule /xyz/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /xyz.php?id3=$1
```

I'm using a hosted server.

also tried without `Options +FollowSymLinks` but still doesn't work. appreciate any advice from someone please.

Comment: should i paste same code  in the .htaccess file in main folder? or any error in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to remove the "/" from "/xyz.php?id3=$1". 
You are in abc folder '/www/abc', and your .htaccess is in the same folder, so the "/" makes the server thinks that the page xyz.php is in the root folder which is /www and not in /www/abc ! 
I had the same problem and I solved it this way!
So try this code:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule /xyz/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) xyz.php?id3=$1
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how that would help solve OP's issue?

Comment: Well, let me try.. he is in abc folder '/www/abc', and his .htaccess is in the same folder, so the "/" makes the server thinks that the page xyz.php is in the root folder which is /www and not in /www/abc!
I had the same problem and I solved it this way!

Comment: Great! Can you please edit it into your answer? (By clicking the Edit button below your answer's text). Welcome to StackOverflow by the way.

Comment: Oh thank :)
Excuse me, I'm new here, I don't exactly know how it really should work, so you asked me to edit it into my answer, do you mean the explanation? do you want me to add it into my answer (by editing it of course)? :D

Comment: Yes, if you could edit it into your answer that would be swell.

Answer (score 0):

Add the domainname in your rule:

```
RewriteRule http://example.com/xyz/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) http://example.com/xyz.php?id3=$1
```

Comment: hi thanks, but still nothing work. i pasted this in .htaccess which is in subdomain folder while the .htacces in main folder leave empty.